# Facebook request not showing notifications

Tags: facebook, notifications, facebook-opengraph

Im using the following code to let users invite their friends in my webapp game:

```
FB.ui({
  method: 'apprequests',
  message: 'Let's play together!'
}, function(response){
  console.log(response);
});
```

But invited friends doesn't receive any notification, they only see the game request in the Gameroom.
The app is set as game, and is already public and visible in the gameroom.

What am I missing?

I also tried to send a notification with the notification api. I get i "success" response, but no notification is shown to the user.

Comment: You are missing nothing. Not every app request will show up as a notification

Comment: @WizKid I tried other games where requests are always sent as notification. How do they do it?